# Bootstrap 3 ordering column into same row in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid-layout

I' m developing a responsive layout but I have problems to sort columns.

I can´t sort columns within a single row.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="well col-sm-8" style="background-color: red">IMAGE col-sm-8</div>
<div class="well col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4" style="background-color: antiquewhite">DESCRIPTION col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4</div>
<div class="well col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8" style="background-color: aqua">PURCHASE col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8</div></div>
```

This code generates the following:

[image]

I need to move the **PURCHASE** section by the **IMAGE** SECTION in the same row.

I am trying with push/pull but this solution does not work in different rows.

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/fAR1F9ULiO#)

**UPDATE**

I am trying use Mobile first.

Mobile version  (is ok)

[image]

Other devices:
**I need organize columns without repeating code.**

In small,medium large devices I need show the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that without repeating due to the following:

From [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

In your case:

```
<div class="well col-sm-8" style="background-color: red">IMAGE col-sm-8</div>
<div class="well col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4" style="background-color: antiquewhite">DESCRIPTION col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4</div>
```

When applying second col-sm-8 you have more than 12 columns so new line will be placed.

The next element that is in the new line, even doing a pull-8 is not able to "jump" to the previous line

```
<div class="well col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8" style="background-color: aqua">PURCHASE col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8</div></div>
```

Comment: I am working with several durandal widgets for that reason I would like to not duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

**Every row amounts to a maximum of 12 col units**.  Of course the PURCHASE well won't fit the same row as IMAGEN if you have 2 cols with size 8 plus you're pushing the second one 4 units.

Answer (score 0):

the code `div class="row"` is each row.
If you want to make PURCHASE section in the same row, you need it to be added in the same `div class="row"` as IMAGEN section.

Is it what you need ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-sm-8" style="background-color: red">IMAGEN col-sm-8</div>
    <div class="well col-sm-4" style="background-color: aqua">PURCHASE col-sm-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4" style="background-color: antiquewhite">DESCRIPTION col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn' fit mobile version. I have updated the question.thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the power of bootstrap. I made a simple demo for you to figure it out. You may try the code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 image">hi</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 purchase">hi</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 desc">hi</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  background: #5ccdde;
}

.purchase {
  background: #ff7162;
}

.desc {
  background: #77e38c;
}
```

Demo can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nu434cqx/)